# jQuery validator counting minimum length plus one in textarea not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a text area that needs a minimum length string to enable the a button.  I am using jQuery validator plugin, and everything works fine, until I get to char 10.  At that point, the message for a minimum number of characters goes away but the button is still disabled.  I have to enter another character (now 11) for the button to be enabled. The functionality, when deleting characters is also incorrect.  The button stays enabled until only 8 characters remain. At the point the button is disabled.  I'm not sure what is going on with it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the html:

```
<textarea id="otherBox" cols="50" class="required" minlength="10"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="sButton" value="Cancel e-Bill" disabled="true" >
```

javascript:

```
var goodLenth = false; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var validator = $("#my_form").validate();


    $("#otherBox").keypress(function(){
        goodLength = validator.element("#otherBox");
        if(goodLenth){
            $("#sButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $("#sButton").attr("disabled","true");
        }
   });
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action http://jsfiddle.net/mg2Bv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built-in callback event functions of the plugin... then you don't have to try to match the events externally.  It's less verbose, more efficient, and easier to maintain.

`success:` - Callback function when an element is validated successfully.

`highlight:` - Callback function when an element fails validation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my_form").validate({
        success: function(label) {
            $("#sButton").prop("disabled", false);
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $("#sButton").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**Working Demo:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/Ufx9G/**

**Documentation:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

**Notes:**

1)  Should not use `removeAttr()` as it *permanently* removes the `attribute`.

2)  Also, should use `prop()` instead of `attr()` as `disabled` is technically a `property` and not an `attribute`.

See:  http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> The `.prop()` method should be used to set `disabled` and `checked` instead
>   of the `.attr()` method.

Comment: Thanks.This is exactly what I was looking for. Also thanks for the heads up on prop vs. attr. For whatever reason, I've found it difficult to find any "good" instructions on using the validate plugin, but since it is so useful, it is hard to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

Dont not use keyPress, this no catch the erase key...

Use keyUp...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var validator = $("#my_form").validate();


    $("#otherBox").keyup(function(){
        goodLength = validator.element("#otherBox");
        if(goodLenth){
            $("#sButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $("#sButton").attr("disabled","true");
        }
   });
});
```

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mg2Bv/1/)

Greetings.

Comment: It's really verbose to re-capture the same keyup events when the plugin is already doing that by default.